# Member deletion in essbase

Tags: hyperion, essbase

I am not able to delete a dimension member in hyperion planning .The error is this
Deletion of member "S104" failed (member might be referenced elsewhere in application).

Answer (score 0):

This typically means that the member is used somewhere else. This can happen in the following ways:

1. There is a shared member somewhere else in the hierarchy with the same name (you would need to delete this as well)
2. There is a member with a formula that explicitly references your member (you would need to modify the formula to remove that member or reference another member)
3. There may be a business rule/calc that references that member by name (adjust business rule/calc to not reference that member)